# Why are the two columns in the HTML table header not aligned with the corresponding columns in the table body

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with two columns.  There are two cells in the header and two cells in the body.  But when I view the page both of the body cells are squeezed under the first cell in the header.  A minimal example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
    Census Administration: Canada Censuses Table Display
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    th.colhead {
                font-family:        sans-serif;
                font-weight:        bold;
                text-align:         center;
                background-color:   #F4E8B0;
                border-top:         thin solid black;
                border-bottom:      medium solid black;
                border-right:       thin solid black;
                }
    .button    { 
                font-family:        sans-serif;
                font-weight:        bold;
                font-size:          80%;
                text-align:         center;
                text-decoration:    none;
                background-color:   #E0E0E0;
                color:              #000000;
                border-top:         2px solid white;
                border-left:        3px solid white;
                border-bottom:      3px solid #606060;
                border-right:       3px solid #606060;
                padding:            2px 12px 2px 12px;
                display:            inline-block;
                }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
      
      <!--- Put out the response as a table -->
      <form name="censusForm">
        <table id="dataTable">
          <thead> <!--- Put out the column headers -->
            <tr id="hdrRow">
              <th class="colhead">
                Source<br>ID
              </th>
              <th class="colhead">
                Districts
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="Row01">
              <td class="button">
                    Source
              </td>
              <td class="button">
                    Districts
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I get the same result on both Chrome and Firefox so I knew I was doing something wrong, but I did not understand why.

If I remove `display: inline-block;` from the button style it works, but padding doesn't work so the "buttons" are not properly placed if the same style is applied to an in-line element.  I also tried inline-flex and inline-grid.  If I tried `block` the two buttons are displayed one on top of each other!

[image: Table as displayed by Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to understand that applying the .button class to a table cell does not work the same as applying it to a `<span>`, `<a>`, or other inline element.  When applied to an inline element you need `display: inline-block` because the default of `inline` does not honor the padding around the "button" and so the appearance of the "button" is wrong.  My application uses `<span class="button">` in help pages where I explain the function of buttons on forms, and it uses `<a class="button">` where the action of the button is implemented by going to another URL rather than invoking the click handler of the element.  But `display: inline-block` overrides the default `display: table-cell` of the  so the resulting element does not occupy the complete width of the column.  So I need two versions of the button style, one for inline elements, which require the `inline-block` so the button is displayed properly, and a separate one for table cells and block elements, such as `<p>` or `<div>` which does not override the default display attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned in his answer, it has to do with understanding the differences between `block`, `inline-block`, and `table-cell`.

Below, I've slightly modified your code to:

- Remove `.button` class from the table cells
- Wrap each cell content in `span` with the `.button` class

Not sure what your intended layout is, but hope this would give you a starting point.

```css
th.colhead {
  font-family:        sans-serif;
  font-weight:        bold;
  text-align:         center;
  background-color:   #F4E8B0;
  border-top:         thin solid black;
  border-bottom:      medium solid black;
  border-right:       thin solid black;
  }
.button { 
  font-family:        sans-serif;
  font-weight:        bold;
  font-size:          80%;
  text-align:         center;
  text-decoration:    none;
  background-color:   #E0E0E0;
  color:              #000000;
  border-top:         2px solid white;
  border-left:        3px solid white;
  border-bottom:      3px solid #606060;
  border-right:       3px solid #606060;
  padding:            2px 12px 2px 12px;
  display:            table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<form name="censusForm">
  <table id="dataTable">
    <thead> <!--- Put out the column headers -->
      <tr id="hdrRow">
        <th class="colhead">
          Source<br>ID
        </th>
        <th class="colhead">
          Districts
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="Row01">
        <td>
           <span class="button">
              Source
           </span>
        </td>
        <td>
           <span class="button">
              Districts
           </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I spent over an hour figuring out what was going wrong and was on the point of posting this as an unsolved question when I finally figured out what I was doing wrong and decided to post the answer.  Your solution works, but requires that I search the entire application for every place where I have a <td class="button">.  This is a very large application. https://github.com/jcobban/Genealogy/wiki

Answer (score 0):

if you explicitly define the width and height and remove display: inline-block this works..

```css
 th.colhead {
                font-family:        sans-serif;
                font-weight:        bold;
                text-align:         center;
                background-color:   #F4E8B0;
                border-top:         thin solid black;
                border-bottom:      medium solid black;
                border-right:       thin solid black;
                 width: 10rem;
                 height: 3rem;
                }
    .button    { 
                font-family:        sans-serif;
                font-weight:        bold;
                font-size:          80%;
                text-align:         center;
                text-decoration:    none;
                background-color:   #E0E0E0;
                color:              #000000;
                border-top:         2px solid white;
                border-left:        3px solid white;
                border-bottom:      3px solid #606060;
                border-right:       3px solid #606060;
                padding:            2px 12px 2px 12px;
/*                 display:            inline-block; */
                width: 10rem;
                 height: 3rem;
               
                }
```

```html
<form name="censusForm">
        <table id="dataTable">
          <thead> <!--- Put out the column headers -->
            <tr id="hdrRow">
              <th class="colhead">
                Source<br>ID
              </th>
              <th class="colhead">
                Districts
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="Row01">
              <td class="button">
                    Source
              </td>
              <td class="button">
                    Districts
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  I cannot explicitly specify the height and width of the table cells because that depends upon the text in the button.  Also while height and width CSS attributes do apply to display: table-cell they do not apply to display: inline which is the default for elements such as <span> and <a> where I use the class button.  That is why I had to defined display: inline-block.